# Is there a way to force a "before_destroy" callback to be trigered first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model which specifies a before destroy callback. Something like:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :do_destroy
  acts_as_destroyable

  private
  def do_destroy
    puts "A"
  end
end

module ActsAsDestroyable
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:extend, ActsMethods)
  end

  module ActsMethods
    def acts_as_destroyable(options = {})
      self.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    end

    module InstanceMethods
      def do_something
        puts "A0"
      end

      def self.included(base)
        base.before_destroy :do_something
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now since the Destroyable module works with Users's assosiacions it needs to have its "do_domething" method executed before the "do_destroy" callback. Any ideas how can I move it up the callback queue?

Comment: try changing the order of `acts_as_destroyable` and `before_destroy` in `User` Model I think it work then

Comment: Will try it, now, though I think it didn't work the last I tried.

Comment: @Viren You were right, I guess I forgot to restart zeus server yesterday or something similar. It works like a charm :) Thanks